# Rendering a huge Tree in Angular2

Tags: angular, tree, rendering, render

Lately, we've encountered some rendering issue.

We have 2,500 (might grow to 5,000) entities represented in a `Tree` data stracture.

We have the whole data in our client-side (pagination is not accaptable in our app, neither with the data already available).

We have some "searching" system that a user can enter the text and it will filter the relevant data.
The problem is - the tree algorithm changes real quick but the rendering takes around 3 seconds.

Moreover, we are representing the data in the View as a tree of accordions. Opening an accordion is just the slowest thing on earth :/

Solutions we've tried:

1. Instead of returning a new tree, we set a hidden property and hence don't need to re-render everything
2. Adding some "shouldRender" property as if to check whether it's even necessary to render some of the entities right now
3. Currently working on some "render according to the users" position in the list" solution.
4. Working with OnPush strategy for all the solutions.

The solutions have benefits on when to render things but none of them gives us a "good enough" result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you looking to gain by posting this? There is no question.

Comment: what browser are you using? i guess you are using firefox here, because there is not way firefox will ever be efficient at rendering 5000 elements (with some sub-elements i suppose) at the same time. the only way to achieve this is to only render what you really need (using ngIf for example)

Comment: I suggest only rendering the visible nodes. Go back to the server, when a node is clicked. If you can display the node list in a scrollable div, then consider implementing an infinite scroll

Comment: Im looking for a solution to my problem. Using Chrome browser. The infinite scrolling seems like a special paging solution. Still seeking for something else. Thanks though :)